# Simple Querying Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have created a database on Firebase with the following structure:

```
employees
    employee-id
        name: "Jhon Doe"
        bio: "Software Developer"
        birthday: "03/23/1986"
recognitions
    recognition-id
        date: "03/23/2017"
        employee: employee-id
        type: "Team Working"
```

How to get **all the recognitions** from my DB with the data of the *employee* too in the same object?

I'm developing this on the web using AngularJS.

Comment: To clarify, you want to build 1 object with all `recognitions` (a list of `recognition-id` objects) and the employee's `employee-id` object data?

Comment: @RadicalFanatic Correct! One object with both information linked using the ID's

Comment: Groovy! I would recommend adding `recognition-id` references to each `employer-id` object. If you're allowed to make this change, I can help you :)

Comment: @RadicalFanatic the fact is that each employee can have many recognitions. How you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the correct way to join between differents references using a unique ID, was the following code:

```
var bigObject = {};

// Find all recognitions
var ref = firebase.database().ref('recognitions');
ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    bigObject = snapshot.val();
    // Loop through all recognitions
    for (o in bigObject) {
        var ref2 = firebase.database().ref('employees').child(bigObject[o].employee);
        ref2.once('value').then(function(snapshot2) {
            bigObject[o].profile = snapshot2.val();
            // Bind the content to the view
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.data = bigObject;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create your own object because `Firebase` does not have the capability of joins on the database side.

```
var bigObject = {};
// Find all recognitions
var ref = firebase.database().ref("recognitions");
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    bigObject = snapshot.val();

    // Loop through all recognitions
    for(o in bigObject) {
        var ref2 = firebase.database().ref("employees").child(bigObject[o].employee);
        ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot2) {
            bigObject[o].employee = snapshat2.val();
        }
    }
});
```

And you'll get something like this:

```
recognitions
    recognition-id
        date: "03/23/2017"
        employee
            name: "Jhon Doe"
            bio: "Software Developer"
            birthday: "03/23/1986"
        type: "Team Working"
```

This will work if you are using the JavaScript SDK (you didn't tag AngularFire)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your help was very useful to me. But check that you have some errors on your answers. I put below the correct solution to get all the information from Firebase.